# laravel site suggests for those who has experience of wordpress development

Tags: laravel

I have more than 3 years of experience in **wordpress** and **php**.

Now I want to getting started with **laravel**.

Can anyone suggest me best links which explains straight forward laravel with latest version.

Comment: have you visited official site https://laravel.com/ ?

Comment: yes i have installed laravel using composer. Also created routes but i am not getting proper tutorial which shows how session,paging,searching,sorting,crud operations  should perform with laravel. All reference sites has messy codes. Can you suggest me clear and nice tutorial sites?

Comment: Laracast can be another good option

Comment: ok. thank you. @sagar Gautam

Comment: It depends on yourself, If you would like lo learn with video tutorials or online sites. Use both of these as necessary you can learn laravel easily

Comment: ok thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

This Series is totally Free to beginner

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start with Laravel is [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4), in combination with [this laracasts series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017).

Laracasts calls itself `a Netflix for Your Career!` and has great tutorials to learn the simple things about Laravel, but also the more in depth parts like unit tests.